# Show red line in switch case statement with menu in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, drop-down-menu, menu, switch-statement

I have faced the error code red line under case R.id.item ( Constant expression required ) to find the id from menu.xml and I have tried to find the problem but I was unable to find it.

[image]

[image]

MainActivity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/black"
   app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
   app:title="ToolBar"
   app:menu="@menu/main_menu">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_2"
        android:title="Item 2"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.rev_menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_1:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message 1",         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.menu_item_2:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, @NonNull Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
}
```

Where's the exact issue?
Note: I tried ( Rebuild project, Clean project, restart the app and create new project :) )

Comment: convert it to `if...else{}`. The switch case is not working with this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android Gradle Plugin 8.0, resource IDs are no longer `final` (see [Android Gradle Plugin 8.0 changelog](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes#default-changes)), and you can't use non-final values a `case`.

You can either :

- Set the `android.nonFinalResIds` property to `false` in your `gradle.properties` file (not recommended),
- Review your code and switch to a simple `if` `else if` statement as mentioned by M DEV.

Comment: when using an if-else statement .. then what does it return?
because :

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_item_1){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
return (???) ; 
    }

Comment: You will not use if-else statements. They make code unreadable. Use only if's. And if if comes true return.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK on first glance. Although few things to check:

- you're using `R` class in your activity (`R.id. menu_item_1`, `R.menu.main_menu` etc.), but I don't see it's imported in `MainActivity` (unless you've removed it from your post). There should be something like below (or whatever your application package is):

```
import com.example.rev_menu.R;
```

- try to check, whether `onOptionsItemSelected` is called at all on menu selection (something like below) - this way you will know at least, if you have a issue with `id` matching, or something else:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getItemId().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```